# ExpandableListview Group Indicator Problem

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have changed the group indicators for my expandable list view using the code snippets below.

However, the group indicators appear `shrinked` and I cant seem to figure why.

The expandablelistview is inside a navigation drawer.

Code and snapshot provided.

Thanks in advance.

Code To Move indicator to right:

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(
            android.R.id.list);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels; 
    expListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - UIUtils.getPxFromDp(getActivity(), 40), width - UIUtils.getPxFromDp(getActivity(),20));
```

Code to change indicator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">            
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_expand_black" android:state_empty="true">  </item>            
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_collapse_black" android:state_expanded="true"></item>                
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_expand_black"></item>
 </selector>

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  .....
 <ExpandableListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          style="@style/ListViewMyApplynxTheme"
          android:groupIndicator="@drawable/explist_custom_group_indicator"
          android:divider="#D3D3D3"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

XML for Group Item which is also the same used for child item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_delete_black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Menu Item"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

Snapshot:

[image: Illustration of problem]

Comment: Can you post the xml of groupe adapter to investigate in this problem

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I just edited with that.

Comment: I think that the space allowed to your image is small then the real size of it(if it's a png), pls try to change the android:layout_width="match_parent" of your textView to android:layout_width="wrap_content" and make the image of indicator in the all folder of drawable (with the scaleed image with this http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)

Comment: I am having same issue. Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

I removed the group indicator like:

```
android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

Then I put an ImageView in the group header. In the Adapter at *getGroupView()*, I gave this ImageView the same functionality as a group indicator:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // initialize ImageView
        ImageView imgExpandCollapse = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgExpandCollapse);

        // check if GroupView is expanded and set imageview for expand/collapse-action
        if(isExpanded){
            imgExpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse);
        }
        else{
            imgExpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_expand);
        }

        return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the scaling you have to use nine-patch images instead of the regular png's:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/KfrpFr4kYOI

How to create 9-patch: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
You can create it in any graphics editor or in the special tool located in sdk\tools directory.
Do not forget name the file like your_file_name.9.png.

Answer (score -1):

follow this link. and give value to setIntrinsicbounds(30, 10) ;

https://androidrant.com/2013/03/02/expandablelistview-group-indicator-bounds-nonsense/

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_empty="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/right">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_expanded="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/down">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```